# Correct way to delete /boot/firmware .bak files in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: boot, command-line, partitioning, find

I'm very new to Ubuntu, I installed the Raspberry Pi Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS (64-bit) image, with their imager tool:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I'm trying to determine the correct way to delete `.bak` files from `/boot/firmware` directory. The `/dev/sda1` partition is almost full:

```
# df -h /dev/sda1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       253M  228M   25M  91% /boot/firmware
```

There are close to 300 `.bak` files in there, taking 114M of partition space (close to 50% of total available space):

```
# find /boot/firmware -type f -name '*.bak' | wc -l
297
# find /boot/firmware -type f -name '*.bak' -exec du -ch {} + | tail -n 1
114M    total
```

I could simply run this command, to delete them:

```
# find /boot/firmware -type f -name '*.bak' -delete
```

Is there a specific Ubuntu command/tool that allows me to purge these `.bak` files, instead of `find -delete` and is it safe to delete them?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: What type/brand of hardware platform are you running Ubuntu on? Is it a kind of integrated board like e.g. a Raspberry PI board? ... `/boot/firmware` is not Ubuntu/ or even *nix specific or present in the standard system hierarchy, so could be a vendor specific requirement maybe and in this case you better follow manufacturer's/vendor's instructions.

Comment: I had no idea. I installed the Raspberry Pi Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS (64-bit) image, with their imager tool. I'll update the question with this info.

Comment: @Raffa Ubuntu for rpi come with `/boot/firmware`.